# Why is my Array's Value Undefined? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to console.log one of the items in my "images" array. Here's the code I have written so far:

```js
var projects = {
    projects : [
        {
            "title" : "Jarvis Systems",
            "dates" : "2015",
            "description" : "A simple control panel for stuff.",
            "images" : ["http://www.bitrebels.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/MAKO-Voice-Recognition-System-3.jpg", "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ah6tHb7eWBY/maxresdefault.jpg"]
        }
    ]
};

console.log(projects.projects.images[0])
```

Sadly, when I run the code, the console says that my array is undefined. How can that be when I just defined it?

Comment: That's because it should be `projects.projects[0].images[0]`, that's a typo

Comment: Oh my gosh. I can't believe I didn't catch that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it `projects.projects[0]` instead of `projects.projects` since `projects` is an array inside `projects`

```js
var projects = {
    projects : [
        {
            "title" : "Jarvis Systems",
            "dates" : "2015",
            "description" : "A simple control panel for stuff.",
            "images" : ["http://www.bitrebels.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/MAKO-Voice-Recognition-System-3.jpg", "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ah6tHb7eWBY/maxresdefault.jpg"]
        }
    ]
};

console.log(projects.projects[0].images[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an array in projects.

```
projects.projects[0].images[0]
//               ^^^
```

```js
var projects = {
    projects : [
        {
            "title" : "Jarvis Systems",
            "dates" : "2015",
            "description" : "A simple control panel for stuff.",
            "images" : ["http://www.bitrebels.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/MAKO-Voice-Recognition-System-3.jpg", "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ah6tHb7eWBY/maxresdefault.jpg"]
        }
    ]
};

console.log(projects.projects[0].images[0])
```